# Add CSS in this Joomla plugin code

Tags: css, plugins, joomla

I created a plugin for Joomla. I have 2 files with names finarchivo.xlm and finarchivo.php. I want to add CSS file. How?

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php 
// No direct access allowed to this file
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin' );

class plgContentFinArchivo extends JPlugin {     
    function plgContentFinArchivo( &$subject ) {
        parent::__construct( $subject );
    }

    function onBeforeDisplayContent(&$article, &$params, $limitstart=0)
    {
        $plugin =& JPluginHelper::getPlugin('content', 'FinArchivo');
        $pluginParams = new JParameter( $plugin->params );
        $mensaje = "";

        $mensaje = $pluginParams->get('mensaje', 'Concurso acabado');

        $salidaPantalla = $mensaje ;
        if($article->state==-1)
            return $salidaPantalla;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [JDocument/addStyleDeclaration](http://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addStyleDeclaration) and [JDocument/addStyleSheet](http://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addStyleSheet).

[JDocument/addStyleDeclaration](http://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addStyleDeclaration):

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$style = '#myid {'
    . 'background-color: #cccccc;'
    . '}'; 
$doc->addStyleDeclaration( $style );
```

[JDocument/addStyleSheet](http://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addStyleSheet):

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet( 'http://www.mydomain.com/css/mystylesheet.css' );
```

Try placing the code inside the `onBeforeDisplayContent` function, eg:

```
function onBeforeDisplayContent(&$article, &$params, $limitstart=0)
{
    $doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
    $style = '#myid {'
        . 'background-color: #cccccc;'
        . '}'; 
    $doc->addStyleDeclaration( $style );

    $plugin =& JPluginHelper::getPlugin('content', 'FinArchivo');
    $pluginParams = new JParameter( $plugin->params );
    $mensaje = "";

    $mensaje = $pluginParams->get('mensaje', 'Concurso acabado');

    $salidaPantalla = $mensaje ;
    if($article->state==-1)
        return $salidaPantalla;
}
```

OR

```
function onBeforeDisplayContent(&$article, &$params, $limitstart=0)
{
    $doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
    $doc->addStyleSheet( 'http://www.mydomain.com/css/mystylesheet.css' );

    $plugin =& JPluginHelper::getPlugin('content', 'FinArchivo');
    $pluginParams = new JParameter( $plugin->params );
    $mensaje = "";

    $mensaje = $pluginParams->get('mensaje', 'Concurso acabado');

    $salidaPantalla = $mensaje ;
    if($article->state==-1)
        return $salidaPantalla;
}
```

Comment: No.I do not understand place the code inside the onBeforeDisplayContent function...

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using? What error are you getting? What happens when the plugin is executed?

Comment: Are you sure the plugin is executing?

Comment: Yes. appears message 'Concurso acabado

Comment: Did you try using `addStyleSheet` or `addStyleDeclaration`?

Comment: What happens if you put `die();` in their place?

Comment: As I can send a picture and the web?. I do not want to disturb

Comment: Is this a a live, production environment site your working on?

Comment: It's bad to test code on a live site. You could quite easily set up a development LAMPP/XAMPP & Joomla environment.